# Can't use where clause with alias count function name

Tags: sql

```
SELECT
   student_id
   ,COUNT(group_id) num
FROM StudentTable
WHERE num >= 2 
GROUP BY student_id 
ORDER BY num
desc
;
```

I keep getting the error: "num" invalid identifier. I don't understand why the where clause doesn't work with the alias name I give it. I already figured out the solution by using the "having" clause. I am just curious as to why the where clause doesn't work because In my mind it makes no sense as to why it doesnt work.

Comment: It doesn't work because *logically* the `where` clause is evaluated before the `select`.  That is, the filtering of the data occurs first, before expensive expressions might be evaluated.  Hence, the alias isn't known for the `where`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't want a `where` clause.  You want a `having` clause:

```
SELECT student_id, COUNT(group_id) num
FROM StudentTable
GROUP BY student_id 
HAVING num >= 2
ORDER BY num desc;
```

Some databases may not accept aliases in the `having` clause.  In that case, you need to use a subquery or repeat the definition:

```
SELECT student_id, COUNT(group_id) num
FROM StudentTable
GROUP BY student_id 
HAVING COUNT(group_id) >= 2
ORDER BY COUNT(group_id) desc;
```

Comment: Will order by num fail as well?

Comment: @Twelfth yes, it will also fail

Comment: @Twelfth . . . It may or may not fail, depending on your database.

Comment: Of course the question isn't tagged.  order by 2 will work for a few databases as well.  Good answer, I'll defer to yours and remove mine

Answer (score 1):

you have to say either `ORDER BY 2` or `ORDER BY COUNT(group_id)`.

The query isn't "aware" of the column alias during the order by clause. The select is the VERY last thing to be run by the query engine.

The same thing applies to the `WHERE` clause.

If you're looking to filter on an aggregate function, using the `HAVING` clause is the best option. And even then, you have to say `COUNT(group_id)`

Comment: and for what its worth, ORDER BY COUNT(group_id) is a MUCH better choice.